# uptime Script help

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, hostname, uptime

I am looking to build a script that will log in to multiple servers using a host file and run uptime, hostname -I and hostname

Script so far

```
echo"" ; 
echo "hostname:" $(ssh $HOST hostname) ;
echo "IP:" $(ssh $HOST hostname -I) ;
echo "uptime" $(ssh $HOST uptime) ;
echo"" ;
```

What would be the best way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: It's probably way overkill, but nagios does that as part of its monitoring.

Comment: What *is* your goal?  You want all this information spit into the terminal or logged to a file?  Sent to an API?  Do you have ssh authorized keys setup on each host or will you need to enter a password?

Comment: This looks like job for Ansible. There is very quick howto which should be sufficient for this task: www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works

Comment: I want the information to display on the terminal and I do have SSH keys set up on each host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want all output in the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts_file=/path/to/file
username=youruser

while read -r host; do
    hostname=$(ssh "${username}@${host}" hostname)
    ip_addr=$(ssh "${username}@${host}" hostname -I)
    uptime=$(ssh "${username}@${host}" uptime)
    echo
    {
        echo "Hostname:?$hostname"
        echo "IP:?$ip_addr"
        echo "uptime:?$uptime"
    } | column -s\? -t
    echo
done <"$hosts_file"
```

This will loop through each line of your hosts_file, assigning the whole line to `host`.  Then it will set the `hostname`, `ip_addr`, and `uptime` to the corresponding results on the remote machine.  It will then echo those results in a columnized format.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Jesse

Comment: If I wanted to use ssh keys I could just append -i /path/to/key after ssh correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try (assuming your hosts in `hostlist` have a correct authentication set up)

```
while read HOST
  do { read HN; read IP; read UP; printf "hostname: %s\nIP: %s\nuptime: %s\n" "$HN" "$IP" "$UP"; } <<< "$(ssh $HOST  "hostname; hostname -I; uptime")"
  done < hostlist
```